# cannot import name 'MSELossFlat' from 'fastai.layers'

Tags: python, fast-ai

I am running the code https://github.com/thiagodma/Pytorch_exs/blob/master/MultiTaskLearning/multitask_age_gender_ethnicity_resnet34.ipynb on Colab.

As I write:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *

from fastai.layers import MSELossFlat, CrossEntropyFlat
from torchvision import transforms
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

files_train = get_image_files("utkface_aligned_cropped/UTKFace")
files_valid = get_image_files("utkface_aligned_cropped/crop_part1")
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-07ceae9afcad> in <module>()
      1 from fastai import *
      2 from fastai.vision import *
----> 3 from fastai.layers import MSELossFlat, CrossEntropyFlat
      4 from torchvision import transforms
      5 import warnings

ImportError: cannot import name 'MSELossFlat' from 'fastai.layers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/fastai/layers.py)
```

Comment: What version of the fastai package do you have?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are referring to a code snippet that used the `fastai` v2 library. In the newest `fastai`, the `MSELossFlat` function can be imported at `fastai.losses`.

But since you are trying out an old code snippet, it's best to reproduce the execution enviroment of that code to get an expected result. I would recommend trying to install `fastai` v2 on your environment and execute the code again.